# Python Updating DataFrame without using Websocket

Tags: python, dataframe, api, websocket, binance

I am new to programming and I've stucked with this problem. Let's say I have a dataframe looks like this:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 09.00 | x |
| 09.05 | y |
| 09.10 | z |
| ... | ... |
| ... | ... |
| 10.00 | a |

I want to update the data every 5 minutes automatically so it would look like this 5 minutes later:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 09.05 | y |
| 09.10 | z |
| ... | ... |
| 10.00 | a |
| 10.05 | b |

Websockets doesn't seem efficent to me because I don't need data every second and I don't have to keep the old data.

Comment: Updating a dataframe... from what kind of data source? You've tagged [tag:api], but [that is a _very_ broad term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am using binance api.